# Getting multiple lineseries component VF charting & dynamic VF

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, visualforce-charting, dynamic-vf-component

I have a requirement where I am asked to have multiple lineseries. The number of line series components is variable.

I tried Dynamic VF components with just one line series and this is the error

*SfdcCore.js:387 Visualforce Chart: Error loading configuration for chart 'jid0jid20': Data retrieval function or object not found: '[object Object],[object Object]'*

```
public Component.Apex.chart getChartComponent()
{
    Component.Apex.Chart chartcmp = new Component.Apex.chart();
    chartcmp.height = '500';
    chartcmp.width = '400';
    List<datapoint> Data = new List<datapoint>();
    datapoint d = new datapoint('Aug');
    d.calls = 3;
    Data.add(d);

    datapoint d1 = new datapoint('Sept');
    d1.calls = 2;
    Data.add(d1);

    chartcmp.data = Data;
    Component.Apex.lineSeries l1 = new Component.Apex.lineSeries();
    l1.axis = 'left';
    l1.xField = 'month';
    l1.yField = 'calls';
    l1.markerType = 'circle';
    l1.markerSize = 2;


    chartcmp.childComponents.add(l1);

    Component.Apex.axis axisleft = new Component.Apex.axis();
    axisleft.type = 'Numeric';
    axisleft.position = 'left';
    axisleft.fields = 'calls';

    chartcmp.childComponents.add(axisleft);

    Component.Apex.axis axisbottom = new Component.Apex.axis();
    axisbottom.type = 'Category';
    axisbottom.position = 'bottom';
    axisbottom.fields = 'month';

    chartcmp.childComponents.add(axisbottom);

    return chartcmp;
}
public class datapoint{
        public String month{set;get;}
        public Integer calls{set;get;}
        public datapoint(String monthname)
        {
            month = monthname;
            calls = 0;
        }
    }
```

The visual page is as follows

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="Account_Plan__c" extensions="AccountPlanEachAccChartHandler">
<apex:pageBlock title="Accounts -  Call Reports"></apex:pageBlock>
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!ChartComponent}"/>
```

Is it possible to generate multiple line series using Dynamic visual force components. If so any reference links for the same?